# Swift: Handle Switch in CustomCell

Tags: swift, tableview, uiswitch

i want to handle my Switches. How can i save the data if UIswitches is change and update my tableview if changed.

later i want to hide a section when the first switch is changed. so how can i do this in this function?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: UITableViewCell!
    let row = indexPath.row


    ///set switch in cells
    goingSwitch = UISwitch(frame:CGRectMake(150, 300, 0, 0));
    goingSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.switchDidChangegoingSwitch(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)


    eventDaySwitch = UISwitch(frame:CGRectMake(150, 300, 0, 0));
    eventDaySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.switchDidChangeEventDaySwitch(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)



    ////// Cells
    switch(indexPath.section){
    case 0:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("detailCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        if row == 0 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Eventname: xxxx"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "okay ausgabe"
        }
        if row == 1 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Eventdate: xxxxxxxx"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Eventdate textausgabe"
        }
    case 1:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("goingCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        if row == 0 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Can you Go to Event? ???"
            cell.accessoryView = goingSwitch
        }
        if row == 1 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Is Going: \(guysareGoing)"

        }

    case 2:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("daysCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = eventdays[row]
        cell.accessoryView = eventDaySwitch
    case 3:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("adminCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = others[row]
    default:
        break
    }


    // return cell
    return cell
}
```

and here the function from switch.

```
func switchDidChangegoingSwitch(sender:UISwitch!)
{


    if (sender.on == true){
        print("goingSwitch is on")
    }
    else{
        print("goingSwitch is off")
    }


}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to move the codes below to ViewDidLoad

```
goingSwitch = UISwitch(frame:CGRectMake(150, 300, 0, 0));
goingSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.switchDidChangegoingSwitch(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
```

Then reload the table at `switchDidChangegoingSwitch()`

Hope it helps.

Jack

Comment: thanks for this trick but if i move this to viewdidload nothing is showing up.